# Is there anyway that I can check if the List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id> is empty in cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to let the user choose the subnet from the cloud formation params and I keep getting errors when the params of the subnet are not selected with any choices.

When I do not select any subnet, it will throw an error `Parameter validation failed: parameter value for parameter name SubnetIds does not exist. Rollback requested by user.`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Parameters:
  SubnetIds:
    Description: "Select multiple subnets from the list"
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>

Conditions:
  SubnetListNotEmpty:
    Fn::Not:
      - Fn::Equals:
          - Fn::Join: ["", !Ref SubnetIds]
          - ""

Resources:
  NullResource:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle

Outputs:
  ConditionValid:
    Description: "valid condition"
    Value: !If [SubnetListNotEmpty, "valid", "invalid"]
```

It would be a good help if anyone could drop some hints.

I understood the error, the `AWS:NoValue` and `""` does not exist in the AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id. How do I handle if there is a chance that the subnet is not needed?

Updated stack

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Parameters:
  SubnetId:
    Description: "Select a subnet ID or leave blank"
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
    Default: ""

Conditions:
  SubnetSelected: !Not [!Equals [!Ref SubnetId, ""]]

Resources:
  NullResource:
    Type:
      AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle
      # Other properties

Outputs:
  SubnetIdOutput:
    Description: "Selected subnet ID or None"
    Value: !If [SubnetSelected, !Ref SubnetId, "None selected"]
```

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: @Paolo i am getting `Parameter validation failed: parameter value for parameter name SubnetIds does not exist. Rollback requested by user.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, because by definition the list cannot be empty. As you found out, AWS performs validation for AWS-specific parameter types, which means that null values are not accepted for such parameter types.

This is confirmed by the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) (emphasis mine)

> AWS-specific parameter types are helpful in catching invalid values at the start of creating or updating a stack. To specify parameters with AWS-specific types, a **template user must enter existing AWS values that are in their AWS account**. AWS CloudFormation validates these input values against existing values in the account.

As a workaround, your best bet is to use a `CommaDelimitedList`, which alas implies not having the nice functionality offered by the AWS-specific parameter types.